# Creating an array of variables whose values can be modified

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, reference

I want something like:

```
this.x=4;
this.y=5;
this.materials = [this.x, this.y];

this.materials[0]=5;//this will change the x variable
```

The result of this should be that the value of my original `x` variable should become 5.

Is such an array of variables possible in Java?

Comment: Not possible in Java. You want something like C++ references. Java doesn't have them.

Comment: @khelwood Yeah, something like C++ references, damn... Thanks for your answer

Comment: why x=5 not 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar (not exactly like that) is possible with objects:

If you had a Number class:

```
class Number {
    int value;

    Number(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And you tried something like this:

```
Number x = new Number(4);
Number y = new Number(5);
Number[] materials = {x, y};

materials[0].value = 5; 
// the value property of the first number object in the array 
// (same as referenced by x) became 5
```

Otherwise, `materials[0] = something` would just replace the first element in the array.

Comment: Wow, that's helps a lot, thanks man, I really appreciate your solution.